# Unable to find VCVarsall.bat using Python 2.7

Tags: python, batch-file, python-2.7

I am working with win 7. Installed Python 2.7. I am trying to setup the source code downloaded from "http://effbot.org/downloads#tkinter3000" 
tkinter3000-1.0-20031212.zip [57k] it throws this error:

```
G:\Python\tkinter3000-1.0-20031212>python setup.py install
using Tcl/Tk libraries at C:\Python27\Tcl
using Tcl/Tk version 8.5
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\WCK
copying WCK\Utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\WCK
copying WCK\wckTkinter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\WCK
copying WCK\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\WCK
creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\tk3
copying tk3\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\tk3
running build_ext
building '_tk3draw' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

I don't have visual studio. Please suggest a workaround to move ahead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: I have seen this... i dont have visual studio..... Martijin

Comment: Did you read the *second* answer on that post?

Comment: Yuppp.... how ming32 will helpp... ??

Comment: You need a compiler. Either Visual Studio or Ming32 provides it.

Comment: and the guy had other tool installation problem.. i a have some other issue

Comment: u mean to say .. without compiler i will not be able to move....

Comment: I only see binaries for Python 2.6 and earlier: http://effbot.org/downloads#tkinter3000, so yes.

Comment: can you please provide any link for downloading ming32 for win7

Comment: Nope, sorry. I don't use Windows at the moment.

Comment: What compiler do you have installed? I had the same bug but was using MinGW so that other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) solved my issue...

Answer (score 2):

In order to compile certain Python 2.7 components you need a c compiler installed.  The compiler expected when looking for VCVarsAll is Microsoft Visual C++.  Microsoft has released a redistributable of the C++ Compiler for use with Python 2.7 that can be retrieved from the following link.

http://aka.ms/vcpython27

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  While this link is a redirect that my team maintains, I will elaborate on the answer here to make sure there is no confusion in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you and, [as explained here](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/64BitCythonExtensionsOnWindows), for Python 2.7 you should use the [3.5 version of the Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18950) which comes with a C compiler.

After installing you have to call the `SetEnv.Cmd` script that will to all the trick with the environment variables. I call it with `SetEnv /x64 /release`, but you should check for aditional flags.

I had a problem with my version (German) of Windows 7 and the `SetEnv.Cmd` was not working properly. This is because the variable names were wrapped between `!!` (exclamation marks) instead of `%%` (percentage symbols). I just replaced them manually and it worked fine...

Answer (score -1):

Download Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 from

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Then don't forget to load setuptools and not distutils, because [distutils has not yet been updated to support this compiler](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/CythonExtensionsOnWindows).

Comment: load setuptools by doing command  "pip install --upgrade setuptools"